# How to disable Angular Drop Down if the model is null or empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I have an angular DropDown , which is bound to scope variable, which is array. I would like disable the dropdown when the array empty.

HTML

```
 <select class="qtDropDown" ng-model="chartModel" ng-options="riskimp.IndustryName for riskimp in riskImprovement"  ng-change="buildChartData(chartModel)"></select>
```

JS

```
if( $scope.riskProfileModel.riskProfileData.RiskImprovment ) 
 {

     //I am doing some chart generation
   }

  else  {

          return null;
       }
```

I am not sure how to disable the drop down. Can anybody suggest how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can set a controller property in javascript return a bool if it is enabled/disabled then you can do the following:

```
<select ng-disabled="isDisabled">
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @Varedis. I am not sure who down voted for u answer, but it totally works the way I wanted it to.

Comment: On reflection you probably don't want to use that as advertised here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled changing the code sample to `ng-disabled="isDisabled"` should perform the same though

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ng-disabled` property to still show the object without hiding it. Add in your element:

```
ng-disabled="chartModel.length == 0"
```